# How the iptables command prints chains containing specific comments

Tags: go, kubernetes, iptables

I have a `golang` project with iptables package(**utiliptables "[k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/iptables](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/iptables)"**) for specific request conditions iptables rules and I expect to check `periodically` to `delete possible dirty data`, I know the `iptables -S` command can print chains but that's `too much` as I have added comments when inserting so I want to `filter chains by comments` and parse them by golang for comparison.

For examples, `commenttest` can be used as a filtered `comment prefix`

```bash
iptables -S PREROUTING -t nat
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "cali:6gwbT8clXdHdC1b1" -j cali-PREROUTING
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -i xxx -p udp -m comment --comment "commenttest:1" -m multiport --dports 12345:12355 -j DNAT --to-destination xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
-A PREROUTING -i xxx -p tcp -m comment --comment "commenttest:2" -m multiport --dports 22222:22233 -j DNAT --to-destination xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
...
...
```

Although it can be filtered by the `pipe and grep` commands, this is not a single command in the `utilexec` package(**"[k8s.io/utils/exec](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/utils/exec)"**), does one exist that can be filtered by a single command?

Is there a parameter to `filter the comment` so that it is in a single command, and if not, is there a command other than the `iptables -S` command to implement the requirement? I really appreciate any help with this.